# Is it possible to use my own private go package in a lambda that is deployed through github actions?

Tags: go, package, yaml, github-actions

I published a private package to my organizations github repository. When I try to deploy a lambda through github actions that uses this package, I get an error saying
"fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly."
Is there an extra line that I need to add to my yml file or would this permission need to be given in the package itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `Configure git for private modules` in the GitHub action, adding one simple step in your workflow, like:

```
  - name: Configure git for private modules
    env:
      GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}
    run: git config --global url."https://x:${GITHUB_API_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
```

And add the `GH_API_TOKEN` secrets in the repo in order to be able to download the go modules during build step, like the `go mod tidy` command.